# Convert dataframe columns of object type to float

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I want to convert all the non float type columns of my dataframe to float ,is there any way i can do it .It would be great if i can do it in One Go .
 Below is the type

```
longitude          -    float64 
latitude          -     float64
housing_median_age   -  float64
total_rooms          -  float64
total_bedrooms       -   object
population           -  float64
households            - float64
median_income         - float64
rooms_per_household   - float64
category_<1H OCEAN    -   uint8
category_INLAND        -  uint8
category_ISLAND        -  uint8
category_NEAR BAY     -   uint8
category_NEAR OCEAN    -  uint8
```

## Below is the snippet of my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

df = pd.DataFrame(housing)
df['ocean_proximity'] = pd.Categorical(df['ocean_proximity']) #type casting 
dfDummies = pd.get_dummies(df['ocean_proximity'], prefix = 'category' )
df = pd.concat([df, dfDummies], axis=1)
print df.head()
housingdata = df
hf = housingdata.drop(['median_house_value','ocean_proximity'], axis=1)
hl = housingdata[['median_house_value']]
hf.fillna(hf.mean,inplace = True)
hl.fillna(hf.mean,inplace = True)
```

Comment: check out [this][1] thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A quick and easy method, if you don't need specific control over downcasting or error-handling, is to use `df = df.astype(float)`.

For more control, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to select columns by dtype. Then use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) on a subset of columns.

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['656', 341.341, 4535],
                   ['545', 4325.132, 562]],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

print(df.dtypes)

col1     object
col2    float64
col3      int64
dtype: object
```

**Solution**

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['float']).columns

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float', errors='coerce')
```

**Result**

```
print(df.dtypes)

col1    float32
col2    float64
col3    float32
dtype: object

print(df)

    col1      col2    col3
0  656.0   341.341  4535.0
1  545.0  4325.132   562.0
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i tried and its not changing.

Comment: cols = hf.select_dtypes(exclude=['float']).columns    /////                                                                
hf[cols] = hf[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float', errors='coerce')

Comment: @avik, Can't reproduce. You should define precisely a dataframe where this solution doesn't work, e.g. define `pd.DataFrame(...)`.

Comment: why not just `df.astype(float) ??` @jpp

Comment: @pyd, That would work too, I've updated with this suggestion. `pd.to_numeric` has more control, you can downcast where possible and can specify what happens with errors.

Comment: @pyd when i used hf.astype(float)  , the error was float argument must be string or  number..

Comment: @avik, Then use the `pd.to_numeric` method. Unfortunately, I can't help debug your problem unless you can provide a [mcve]. E.g. build a *minimal* dataframe from scratch `pd.DataFrame(....)` to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @pyd .thanks for your help ..i was able to convert all the columns except the one in object type that is total_bedrooms.   ex code i used.:                                    
  hf['category_NEAR OCEAN'] = hf['category_NEAR OCEAN'].astype(float)

Comment: also what i found is that when i use "hf.fillna(hf.mean,inplace = True)  that converts   the datatype of that total_bedrooms to objects

Comment: can you create a new question with your actual df and expected df

Comment: thank you , the error as due to me using ,hf.fillna(hf.mean,inplace = True) it should be hf.fillna(hf.mean(),inplace = True)

Comment: pd.to_numeric didn't work for me. as_type(float) did.

Answer (score 0):

**Enumerate Convert to numeric and insert to a new dataframe**

```
New_DataFrame = pd.DataFrame()
x = {New_DataFrame.insert(i, name, pd.to_numeric(df[name], errors = "coerce"), True) if(df[name].dtype.name=='object') else New_DataFrame.insert(i, name, df[name], True) for i, name in enumerate(df.columns)}
print(New_DataFrame.head())`
```

Comment: downcast='float' add for your required type